# C# Regular Expressions search

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regular expressions to search some text (an equation).

I might have something like this

> (A) (x + 5) (( testthis ))

I have an option to search for the whole word only or for partial words.

Here are a few conditions for the above example that I'd like to meet, but don't seem to work with any options that I've tried

1. Whole word search for `(A)` should return a match.
2. Whole word search for `A` should not return a match.
3. Partial word search for `A` should return a match.
4. Whole word search for `((` should return a match since there is a space on each side of the brackets around `(( testthis ))`.

I have tried the code below as well as many other combinations such as `\\b \\b* \\S* \\W`.

I basically want the same functionality as \b but with support for non-alphanumeric characters.

```
if (bWholeword == true)
{
      matchText = "\\s*" + Regex.Escape(term) + "\\s*";
}
else
{
      matchText = Regex.Escape(term);
}
```

Comment: It would really improve your question if you'd tell what's wrong with the final piece of code. Now it just sits there.

Comment: sorry in this case, if you have (test) and search for whole word (test) it will not find it.   If you have test without the brackets and search, it will.   Basically brackets are throwing a wrench in everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matchText = bWholeword 
             ? (@"(^|(?<=[\b\W|_]))" + term + @"($|(?=[\b\W|_]))") 
             : term;
```

`(^|(?<=[\b\W|_]))` matches either the start of the string, or any non-alphanumeric (only grabbing the term though).  And same for the end.

It's gets tricky when your term is `(` or similar.  It will match once on each `(` because they are both whole words, around nonalphanumeric characters.

Comment: this works if I change it to (@"(^|(?<=[\b\W|_]))" + RegEx.Escape(term) + @"($|(?=[\b\W|_]))").    Otherwise, a search for "test))" will return a too many bracket error.

Comment: One other limitation is this:
if I have the term ((test) and search for a whole word match of (test) it finds it.   I'm not sure if this is proper behavior for a whole word search or not.